# How to use listeditor as a dialog box?

Tags: java, eclipse

I want a dialog box which will have three more button in the buttonbar as selectall,up & down button with ok & cancel button.Can I use listeditor here and how it will be?

Answer (score 1):

You can override `ListEditor.getButtonBoxControl()`. See this [sample](http://sandipchitale.blogspot.ca/2008/09/enhanced-listeditor-implementation.html).

Comment: I only need selectall,up & down button.No need of the add & remove button.Can I remove those buttons from listeditor?

Comment: @Anu , you have access to buttons - ie `getAddButton()`. In your implementation of `getButtonBoxControl()`, try removing/disposing these buttons from the `Composite` that is returned by `super.getButtonBoxControl()`. Check out Eclipse's [ListEditor.java](https://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/IDE-Eclipse/jface/org/eclipse/jface/preference/ListEditor.java.htm) implementation for details.